# how to query in memsql like “select … for update” mysql query? is it impossible?

Tags: singlestore

I want to acquire read lock when executing memsql query like mysql query `select ... for update`

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Select for update is not supported currently, but will be available in the upcoming 6.7 release of MemSQL.

What's the context of what you need it for? There may be workarounds available in the current version of MemSQL.